# Saving form data in configuration observer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration, save, request

I have a field in store configuration that has a select per store that contains a language setting.

[image: languages]

I've also written an observer that fires when this section of store configuration is saved. However the request's parameters don't contain the select choices from the store configuration form. `$this->_resquest->getParams()` only yields `[section]`, `[key]`, `[form_key]`, `[config_state]`, and `[groups]`.

Why aren't the choices from the select elements present in the request?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: VIPIN A ROY, I just used links instead of select elements. The links would redirect to the respective store configuration.